# iOS7 - How to get image from xcassets for static library?

Tags: ios, uiimage, bundle, static-libraries, assets

Now I have one static library with it's own bundle, I want create xcassets in bundle for image, I konw the method `imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:` can load image, but our application also support iOS7, and that method for iOS8. The method `imageNamed:` only load image from main bundle .
So is there have some simple method to support the scene of custome bundle whit xcassets ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path to load the image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"../../xx.jpg"];
```